# Parsing time formats in R

Tags: r, date, datetime

Is there a way for me to parse the following string in a date time format in R which includes not just the date but also the time zone (+08:00). The time zone here is actually not that important but would be good to include. I've tried using as.Date and as.POSIXct but both throws me NA. My main aim of converting into date time is to be able to sort them by time and also filter the data frame by time when necessary.

```
01 Jul 2019 12:56:43 +08:00
```

Would be glad to provide more information if required.

Answer (score 4):

The package `lubridate` is a godd choice to parse (and work with) dates:

```
library(lubridate)

dmy_hms("01 Jul 2019 12:56:43 +08:00")
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `dmy_hms` function from `lubridate` package as others have suggested but be sure to specify the local timezone you desire to use via the `tz` argument.

```r
lurbidate::dmy_hms("01 Jul 2019 12:56:43 +08:00", tz = "America/Chicago")

R> dmy_hms(date, tz = "America/Chicago")
Date in ISO8601 format; converting timezone from UTC to "America/Chicago".
[1] "2019-06-30 23:56:43 CDT"
```

For an extensive list of available timezones, execute

```r
OlsonNames(tzdir = NULL)

R> OlsonNames(tzdir = NULL)
  [1] "Africa/Abidjan"                   "Africa/Accra"                     "Africa/Addis_Ababa"              
  [4] "Africa/Algiers"                   "Africa/Asmara"                    "Africa/Asmera"                   
  [7] "Africa/Bamako"                    "Africa/Bangui"                    "Africa/Banjul"                   
 [10] "Africa/Bissau"                    "Africa/Blantyre"                  "Africa/Brazzaville"              
 [13] "Africa/Bujumbura"                 "Africa/Cairo"                     "Africa/Casablanca"               
 [16] "Africa/Ceuta"                     "Africa/Conakry"                   "Africa/Dakar"                    
 [19] "Africa/Dar_es_Salaam"             "Africa/Djibouti"                  "Africa/Douala"                   
 [22] "Africa/El_Aaiun"                  "Africa/Freetown"                  "Africa/Gaborone"                 
 [25] "Africa/Harare"                    "Africa/Johannesburg"              "Africa/Juba"                     
 [28] "Africa/Kampala"                   "Africa/Khartoum"                  "Africa/Kigali" 
...
```

Comment: That's a good hint! However this will only effect display; results of calculations will be correct in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible with base R `as.POSIXct` and `strptime` as well

```
as.POSIXct("01 Jul 2019 12:56:43 +08:00", format = "%d %b %Y %T")
```

OR

```
strptime("01 Jul 2019 12:56:43 +08:00", format = "%d %b %Y %T")
```

Comment: Need to add `%z` and remove colon from offset:  `as.POSIXct(sub(":(..)$", "\\1", "01 Jul 2019 12:56:43 +09:00"), format = "%d %b %Y %T %z")`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I am surprised but this still works for me `as.POSIXct("01 Jul 2019 12:56:43 +08:00", format = "%d %b %Y %T")`  `#[1] "2019-07-01 12:56:43 +08"`

Comment: With the code in the answer, on Windows R 3.5.3 if I change the +08:00 to +09:00 I still get the same result.